# SpringData extending JpaSpecificationExecutor error

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have very strange problem. In my repository, i need to extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>` interface to be able to use `findAll(Specification<T>, Pageable)` for custom query paging.

But, when I use the JpaSpecificationExecutor,

```
public interface DescriptionRepository extends ParentRepositoryCustom<Description, Long>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<Description> {

}
```

application won´t build, throwing `No property count found for type class Description` exception.

My `Description` class has no count attribute. When I remove `JpaSpecificationExecutor` from repository, everything works well again.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same exception. In my case, the reason was that the 
ParentRepositoryImpl was NOT exending correctly SimpleJpaRepository
which is an implementation of JpaSpecificationExecutor.
So when Spring try to resolve the query names, it exludes the method names belonging to what Spring call the repositoryBaseClass of your implementation. It s in the class org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.DefaultRepositoryInformation

```
public boolean isBaseClassMethod(Method method) {
    return isTargetClassMethod(method, repositoryBaseClass);
}
```

Check that repositoryBaseClass is what you expect. It should defines the "count" method.

If you don't extends the correct superclass, the method ("count" in your case) is not excluded form resolution and Spring tries to build a query by creating it according to its name structure ... and in that case fragment of name are tested against your entity property.